# is there a limit on how many times I can use .read on the same file?

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, mat

```
VideoCapture capVideo;
capVideo.read(imgFrame2);
```

is there a limit on how many times I can use .read on the same file?

Comment: No. Why would there be a limit? You need to call `read` indefinitely when working with live camera sources, for example.

Comment: Probably depends on what `capVideo` is. Hard to say anything if we don't know what function you are calling.

Comment: @churill capVideo is from VideoCapture capVideo;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no limit. Each time you call read function, new frame is returned unless there's an error (end of video file, error while capturing image from the camera etc).

Comment: so I can have like 10 read function reading from the same video file and use all 10 for different purposes?

Comment: Definitely. Remember that each time you call read different frame is returned.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "different frame is returned"?